# How to structure components

Tags: reactjs

I'm just starting to learn react and I'm wondering what the best way to structure one of my test projects.

The application is one page, and has to:

- Have a search that hits an external API, returning JSON.
- The JSON result will be shown to the User in a readable format
- Have buttons with dynamic links
- Have a dropdown with some of the json data

I'm thinking there should be a component for each of those, with the associations setup as the 'Search' being the parent component, with each of the other components inheriting directly from that..

For example:

```
app
│   ├── search component
│   │   ├── dropdown component
│   │   ├── list component
│   │   ├── button component
│   │
```

This feels like the wrong approach though. I was looking at redux for state management but thought it was a bit too overkill. Since I need access to the searches data for each of the components, is there a better way to structure this that allows for that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component design seems appropriate for the application you are trying to build. Redux would indeed be an overkill in your case, provided the data from the api is simple and the state can be managed by the parent component.

A few pointers for your path ahead:

1. Call the api in `componentDidMount` of your `Search` component to get the JSON data and save it to the `state` of the component.
2. Create a `Loading` component, which would be displayed in your `Search` component, while your api call completes (`state` does not have data).
3. Pass the json data from the `state` of `Search` to its child components as `props`. Only pass the part of the `state` that is relevant to the child.
4. Pass actions from the `Search` component to the children for handling any changes in data due to any events (like button onClick, dropdown onChange  etc.).These actions would modify the `state` of the `Search` component and pass the changes to the child components through props.

Hope this helps!